# Initials, we are

Tags: knowledge, pattern, visual, rebus

Can you tell me what this sequence represents? (something very well-known)

---

[image]

Comment: @Smartest1here Thanks! Keep going, I'll add a hint later today :)

Comment: I think I have 3 of these already.

Comment: @AntsPiano, please do not make guesses in comments. That's not how the answering system works. If you think that you have made progress, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rebus explanation:

1.

> 1111101101 (binary) converts to 1005 (decimal), which in Roman numerals is **MV**

2. 

> EMU but the U got to go --> **EM**

3. (thanks to Stiv!)

> The word "unlucky" refers to the number 13. Using ROT13 cipher (in which A = N and N = A) the W will become a **J**.

4. 

> SUNGLASSES, MINUS (electrons are negatively charged and often represented with a - sign), GLASSES --> **SUN**

Together they form

> **MVEMJSUN**, aka the initials of our Solar System's eight planets: *Mercury, Venus, Earth, Mars, Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus, Neptune*. Which is indeed something very well-known, and also explains the puzzle title.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling (and Merry Christmas)! You're on a roll today! Your missing one is a trick you'll come to know about if you hang around on Puzzling - we often use a cipher called [rot13](https://rot13.com/) to hide spoilers and the like on this site, which simply moves a letter 13 spaces on (or back) through the alphabet. The 'unlucky' in the image is a hint to use this (link with 13) - and if you do this to the 'W' you get 'J'. Congrats on some good answering and I hope you stick around :)

Comment: Thank you @Stiv! I should have noticed that, will edit my answer now :)

Answer (score 0):

Could have something to do with

> a Smart Device Application Emulator

1. 

> 1111101101 - computer language **1's and 0's**
>  (Initially thought 10-bit)

2. 

> **EMU** + (you got to go)response: **LATER**! = **EMULATOR**

3. 

> ROT13 + Wordpress = **ENCRYPTION** and **COMPRESSION**

4. 

> Polarized + glass + electricity = **Cellphone screen** or **Monitor**
>  (Initially thought smart glass - electronically tinting glass)

So,

> Perhaps as a sequence,
>  the code is input
>  into the emulator
>  where it is encrypted and compressed
>  and then displayed onto the screen

Title

> Possibly types of cellphone OS, but a stretch:
>  **I**nitials (**IOS**), 
>  **W**e (**Windows**) 
>  **A**re (**Android**)

Thoughts

> This is kind of partial, but if it helps someone else, go with it.

Comment: I think 2 is correct. But how will you explain the title with this?

Comment: Personally I think 2 is more likely to be just rot13(RZ - RZH bapr 'lbh' (H) unf tbar. Guvf pbhyq nyfb znxr frafr bs ybbxvat sbe *vavgvnyf* gbb...)

Comment: @Stiv, That's very possible and I like your thinking as always. I am unable to work that in though. Since that's the basis for my entire answer. LOL.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you what it represents as I suspect it's a pop-culture reference...

> possibly Star-Wars related as the title is very Yoda-esque,

... but I'm unfamiliar with it, so here's where I've got to with each item:

1.

> Binary, BIN, the number 1005, or 10-bits. Also a character code for ϭ which looks like a Russian 'b' but is actually *Coptic Small Letter Shima* in unicode.

2. 

> The Australian **Emu War** of 1932: *a nuisance wildlife management military operation undertaken in Australia over the latter part of 1932* according to Wikipedia ( hence *'you got to go'* ). The initials here must be **EW**.

3. 

> Rot13 of WP (WordPress) gives initials **JC** (Jesus Christ?)

4. 

> Seeing electrons in glass $\rightarrow$ **TV** or CRT screen?
>  Maybe this also refers to JJ Thomson who discovered the electron?